# Whenever gem - 2 Rails apps on one machine, --update-crontab overwrites crontab from other app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

I have 2 separate Rails apps on the same machine. Both use Whenever.  --update-crontab works when setup for one app, but when run again for the other app, it overrides the crontab so my jobs from the first app no longer execute per the schedule.

Any suggestions to get around this?

Comment: You could run the 2 apps as different users? That would give you 2 different Crontabs, although it'd be a faff

Comment: Thx - I can't see why Whenever can add a flag on the whenever CLI to append versus over-write.  One idea i thought of is going into `crontab -e` and in `vi` add the additional entries.

Comment: That's the only way I would do it myself, tbh, I never trust any program to change my crontab entries.